# Always indicate incorrect

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

Even you answer is correct, it will still indicate it is incorrect .

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string play;

    cout << "Do you want to play? ";
    cin >> play;

    if (play == "yes") {
        cout << "Ok, Let's Get Started! \n";
    } else {
        cout << "Let's play next time!";
    }

    string test1;

    cout << "What does CPU stand for? ";
    cin >> test1;

    if (test1 == "central processing unit") {
        cout << "Correct!\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Incorrect!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I try to redo/recode the `if else` statement but it didn't run. I'm expecting that there some expert can help me.

Comment: Change your `cin >>` for `std::getline(cin, `. Otherwise, the second `cin >>` will only read one string, e.g. `central`: https://godbolt.org/z/aYeEqzaPW

Comment: Reopened as the suggested dupe referred to the char array version of getline, not the string version that is probably needed here.

Comment: By the way, don't mix `cin >>` and `std::getline(cin, `. If you use `cin >> play;` and then `std::getline(cin, test1);`, the `std::getline` will read a whitespace or a newline that the `cin >> play;` left without reading: https://godbolt.org/z/j1EzabP77

Comment: A good first step when the output is mysterious is to verify that the input is what you expect instead of assuming that it is. Add `cout << test1;` before the conditional.

Comment: `cin >> test1;` only reads the first word of `central processing unit` so that `if (test1 == "central processing unit") {` can never be true regardless of what the user typed.

Comment: FYI, execution continues if `play != "yes"`.  You may want to put a `return` statement inside the `else` clause so the program ends.

Answer (score 3):

This statement

```
cin >> test1;
```

reads a **single** word, so it can never read the three words of 'central processing unit'. If you want to read lines of text then use `getline`

```
getline(cin, play);
```

and

```
getline(cin, test1);
```

Comment: its not running  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string play;

cout << "Do you want to play? ";

getline(cin, play);

if (play == "yes"){
    cout << "Ok, Let's Get Started! \n";
}else{
    cout << "Let's play next time!";
}

 getline(cin, test1);

cout << "What does CPU stand for? ";
cin >> test1;

  if (test1 == "centralprocessingunit"){
cout << "Correct!\n";
} else{
    cout << "Incorrect!\n";
}
    return 0;
}

Comment: @ArvinCalinog Your code is still says `cin >> test1;` and `getline` has been added in the wrong place.

Comment: can some body show me where i will put the getline? my mind is confused rightnow

Comment: Instead of `cin >> test1;`. You did the right thing when you replaced `cin >> play;` with `getline(cin, play);`, you did the wrong then when you added `getline(cin, test1);` before your prompt and left `cin >> test1;` in place.

Comment: There should be a `return` statement in the first `else` clause; otherwise execution keeps going when `play != "yes"`.